# Laravel Searchbar Class 'products' not found / ProductController@?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am an Laravel beginnner and try now to build an Simple Searchbar on my site.

But I get this error:

> Class 'products' not found

Can someone tell me please what I have forget in my Controllers?

**Search form on Index:**

```
 <ul class="searchbar">
    <form action="/search" class="light" method="POST" role="search">
 {{ csrf_field() }}
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" placeholder="Find your item" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
```

**search.blade.php:**

```
@extends('master.main')

@if(Auth::check())

@section('main-content')

  @component('master.notification')

    @slot('size')

    col-md-8 col-md-offset-2

    @endslot

    @slot('title')

    Product Search

    @endslot

    <div class="container">
    @if(isset($products))
    <h2>Product Search</h2>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($products as $dummy)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$dummy->name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$dummy->description}}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach

            </tbody>
        </table>
        {!! $products->render() !!}@endif
    </div>
        <div class="container">
            @if(isset($details))
            <p> The Search results for <b> {{ $query }} </b> are :</p>
            <h2>Product Search</h2>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach($details as $products)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$products->name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$products->description}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>

            @if($details){!! $details->render() !!}@endif
            @elseif(isset($message))
            <p>{{ $message }}</p>
            @endif
        </div>

  @endcomponent

@stop

@endif
```

**web.php:**

```
Route::get ( '/', function () {
    $mydatabase = products::paginate(25);
    return view ( 'search' )->withproducts($mydatabase);
} );

Route::any ( '/search', function () {
    $q = Input::get ( 'q' );
    if($q != ""){
    $products = products::where ( 'name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->orWhere ( 'description', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->paginate (5)->setPath ( '' );
    $pagination = $products->appends ( array (
                'q' => Input::get ( 'q' ) 
        ) );
    if (count ( $products ) > 0)
        return view ( 'search' )->withDetails ( $products )->withQuery ( $q );
    }
        return view ( 'search' )->withMessage ( 'No Products found. Try to search again !' );
} );
```

**The error comes from:**

> Route::get ( '/', function () {
>       $mydatabase = products::paginate(25);

How is `products` or `Product::paginate` defined or must I use in `web.php` the `ProductController@...`? Yes, I have found out its not my database table `products` ;) I think `Product` instead of `products` are correct, right?

**/App/Product.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Storage;

class Product extends Model
{
    public function category(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
    public function seller(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function buyer(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function bids(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Bid');
    }
    public function purchases(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Purchase');
    }



}
```

Comment: you have to include product model in routes. did you included it? did you made product model ? is model name same as database table?

Comment: Share your model page ?

Comment: App/Product.php (Model Page) added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must add (import your class products) in the begin of your controller (web.php for your case)

```
use namespace\products
```

replace namespace by your namespace(the path of the class products) exemple: \app
is better to use a controller ProductController and redefined yours functions

Comment: in my web.php file i have added now: use app\Product. But get an error, maybe not correct

Answer (score 0):

If your products model is `Product` then you have typo in your code.

```
Route::get ( '/', function () {
$mydatabase = Products::paginate(25);
return view ( 'search' )->withproducts($mydatabase);
} );
```

You have a typo in your code change `products::paginate` to `Product::paginate()`

Hope this helps

Comment: Product Model Page added, can you please review it? I hope its the correct page.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `products::paginate` with `\App\products::paginate`?

Laravel is namespaced, therefore it cannot find a class just by the correct name.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5 promotes the use of namespaces for things like Models and Controllers. Your Model is under the App namespace, so your code needs to call it like this:

Route::get('/', function(){

```
    $myDatabase= \App\Products::paginate(25);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Big Thanks guys for your Help!

I have just must added

> use App\Product;

to my web.php file and works great!